# How to create a datastore.Text object out of an array of dynamically created Strings?

Tags: java, string, google-app-engine

I am creating a Google App Engine server for a project where I receive a large quantity of data via an HTTP POST request.

The data is separated into lines, with 200 characters per line. The number of lines can go into the hundreds, so 10's of thousands of characters total.

What I want to do is concatenate all of those lines into a single Text object, since Strings have a maximum length of 500 characters but the Text object can be as large as 1MB.

Here is what I thought of so far:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
...

String[] audioSampleData = new String[numberOfLines];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
{
  audioSampleData[i] = req.getReader().readLine(); 
}

com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text textAudioSampleData = new 
                         Text(audioSampleData[0] + audioSampleData[1] + ...);

...
}
```

But as you can see, I don't know how to do this without knowing the number of lines before-hand. Is there a way for me to iterate through the String indexes within the Text constructor? I can't seem to find anything on that.

Of note is that the Text object can't be modified after being created, and it must have a String as parameter for the constructor. (Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text#Text(java.lang.String)))

Is there any way to this? I need all of the data in the String array in one Text object.

Many Thanks!

Comment: am i missing something here. why can't you just concatenate a string in the for loop, then pass that into the Text constructor?!

Comment: Because the string I would be concatenating in the for loop would be far too long (limit 500 chars).

Comment: Why is the limit 500 characters? I've never heard of that before. It's been a while since I've done any java mind. Wouldn't you use a StringBuilder in the loop, then sb.toString() for the input to your Text constructor?

Comment: It might be a google-app-engine specific thing (the 500 char limit). Currently looking into StringBuilder

Comment: Posted some sample code. Apologies if I'm missing the point!

Comment: I think you may be confusing a Java String with a datastore string. A Java String, as far as I know, can be as big as the memory you have available, give or take.

Comment: How can I differentiate between the two in my code?

Comment: I think I've found the source of confusion. The javadoc says "Text wraps around a string of unlimited size. Ordinary Java strings stored as properties in Entity objects are limited to 500 characters. However, Text objects can also be stored in properties, and are unlimited in size. However, they will not be indexed for query purposes.". So basically, if you set an entity property with a String, then it will be truncated to 500 characters. If you need to use more than 500 characters, then you will need to use a Text object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some different ways to do this.  FYI, I have have only compiled these, I have not run them.

**Option A:** Probably the simplest of the three

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    // change initialCapacity to reflect the likely final size
    int initialCapacity = 1024;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(initialCapacity);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        int c;

        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // your error handling here
    }

    String s = builder.toString();
    Text text = new Text(s);

    // etc etc.
}
```

**Option B:** This one converts a line at a time, but if the content is in fact not newline separated, then it's going to be a really big single line.  Also, as the loop appends each line to the StringBuilder, note that the string being appended has \n and \r characters stripped out.  So if your goal was to preserve the line terminators, this one isn't a great choice.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    // change initialCapacity to reflect the likely final size
    int initialCapacity = 1024; 

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(initialCapacity);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // your error handling here
    }

    String s = builder.toString();
    Text text = new Text(s);
    // etc etc.
}
```

**Option C:** This one uses a character buffer to read from the reader and write to the string buffer in bulk.  It also preserves the line terminating characters.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    // change initialCapacity to reflect the likely final size
    int initialCapacity = 1024;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(initialCapacity);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        char [] buffer = new char[1024];

        int charsRead = 0;
        do {
            charsRead = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (charsRead > 0) {
                builder.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
            }
        } while (charsRead != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // your error handling here
    }

    String s = builder.toString();
    Text text = new Text(s);

    // etc etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder to build your string, then convert to String for the constructor ...

```
StringBuilder audioSampleData = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
  audioSampleData.append(req.getReader().readLine()); 
}

Text textAudioSampleData = new Text(audioSampleData.toString());
```